# Persisting DataSource in GridView after PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

So I have a GridView in my ASPX page.

When I click `<asp:Button id="btnBindIt" runat="server" />` it binds a datatable as follows:

```
theDataTable = GetAllTheRecords();
gvTheGridView.DataSource = theDataTable;
gvTheGridView.DataBind();
```

Note: `theDataTable` is a member

```
private DataTable theDataTable;
```

This works as expected.

Now, after the GridView is displayed nicely, I want to export the data to CSV, so I now click the `<asp:Button id="btnExportIt" runat="server" />` which runs the code:

```
exportToCsv(theDataTable);
```

but `theDataTable` is null.

So I tried

```
exportToCsv(gvTheGridView.DataSource)
```

Which is also null.

What's the standard way of persisting this data? I don't really want to hit the DB again as it's quite a long SPROC and the user has already waited once.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers everyone.

I steer clear of putting stuff into the VeiwState or session unnecessarily, so I think the best way to persist this data is to Cache it.

I think the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) is the most appropriate place for this, is is how I ended up implementing it.

Comment: -1: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408117/why-isnt-caching-system-web-caching-cache-used-for-state-management

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to store large amounts of data like this in the session. For me, my solution was to not store the results that I planned on databinding, but to make the query that got the results faster by caching. It worked well for my situation.

Answer (score 11):

Class level variables can't maintain their value on postback.

But there are two ways you can maintain Data on the Page's PostBack: `ViewState and Session State`.
But I would suggest in your Scenario to put it in the `ViewState`.

```
ViewState["theDataTable"] = theDataTable;
Session["theDataTable"] = theDataTable;
```

And then you can access it on the page postback:

```
DataTable theDataTable = (DataTable)ViewState["theDataTable"];
DataTable theDataTable = (DataTable)Session["theDataTable"];
```

Comment: Thank Muhammed.

I'm concerned with using the session or viewstate with a large dataset. Would you recommend doing this for a large dataset?

Comment: What if you export Gridview data to CSV ?

Comment: Another way is, you can iterate your Gridview Rows on server and extract DataTable from Gridview and then export it csv.

Answer (score 5):

Declare the datatable as follows and everything will work as expected

```
    private string _theDataTable="theDataTable";
    private DataTable theDataTable
    {
            get
            {
                    if(ViewState[_theDataTable]==null)
                            return new DataTable();
                    return (DataTable)ViewState[_theDataTable];
            }
            set
            {
                    ViewState[_theDataTable] = value;
            }
    }
```

cheers!

Comment: instead of writing `return new DataTable();` in case of ViewState being null, it would be better to get fresh data from the data source (database or what ever it is).