# Reset values inside a repeater

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater

I have a repeater which displays products. Users can select a `Size - dropdownlist` and an `Amount - textbox`. Then they press `Order` or `Cancel`. When they press `Cancel` I would like the values of `Size` and `Amount` to return to their default values.

```
Protected Sub lbtnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lbtnCancel.Click
    rpt.ProductList is the repeater name

    lblFeedback.Text = ("")
    lblFeedback.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Black
End Sub
```

Any help is welcome!

I am using VB.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you `rebind` your repeater on the `Cancel Click`, so it will again be populated with your `Default Values` ?

Comment: How you are binding first time ? that's the similar way I think :)

Comment: I use a query to populate them items. Isn't that quite intensive?

Comment: you can , but If you don't want to query to DB again, then you can put that datasource in some where in ViewState/sessionState and then rebind with that. look onto this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119542/persisting-datasource-in-gridview-after-postback/6119557#6119557

Comment: is there really no other way to do so?

Comment: I think that case will be more difficult what I have give you an option in my answer.  You have to maintain orginal value and check which value is changed and I think this is more difficult and time consuming.

Comment: Couldn't I just clear the textbox and set the dropdown to it's default value?

Comment: Hmm it worked using rptProductList.Dispose() and then rptProductList.Databind()

Comment: and that's what I was asking to Rebind the Repeater. rebind mean. bind it again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the rptProductList_ItemCommand event to catch the repeateritem line and play with the controls as you please ...